# I cannot find credentials for log in in VM downloaded from Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, virtualbox, gcloud

I have just downloaded the copy of my running instance of a VM and I have converted it in a .VDI file so I can run it in my VirtualBox.

When I start it I am prompted in the login page but I cannot find any credentials for login in the VM.
Does anyone knows where can i find it?

I have tried to find the password using SSH but there is no way to decrypt it.
I have also tried to login with my account credentials, email and password but it doesn't work.

The Virtual Machine also gave me an hint: "num lock on". I don't know if it can be useful.
Thank you

P.S. I have full access at GCP panel (but I am not superadmin)

Comment: Google VMs do not have password-based login enabled. Connect using the SSH keypair. If you do not have the SSH private key, set up the VM first for authentication and then download the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to a GCE instance (VM) with a third-party tool outside of Google Cloud Platform you must generate your own SSH key pair and provide your public SSH key file to the instance before you can connect.

To create your [key pair](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys):

> **Linux and macOS**
>
> 1. Open a terminal and run
>
>    ```
>    ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME] -C [USERNAME]
>    ```
>
> Where `[KEY_FILENAME]` is the name of the file where you create the
> keys and `[USERNAME]` is the name of the user connecting to the VM.
>
> 2. Restrict access to your private key
>
>    ```
>    chmod 400 ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME]
>    ```
>
> **Windows**
>
> 1. Download [puttygen.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html).
> 2. Run puttygen.
> 3. Click **Generate** and follow the instructions.
> 4. In the Key comment section, replace the existing text with the username of the user who will use the key to connect to the VM.
> 5. Click **Save private key** to write your private key to a file with a `.ppk` extension.
> 6. Click **Save public key** to write your public key to a file for later use.
>
> After that you have to provide the SSH key to your instance. The best
> way to do that is enabling [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access).